# Android remove fragment by container

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently, I am working on a new android project.
In my project, I have 2 FrameLayout (called F1, F2) which are used as containers of Fragment.

On "F1" I will add a fragment (Like navigation drawer fragment, menu item....).

On "F2" I called its MainContainer - It's will use container all "Main" fragment. (I mean F2 will container fragment like HomeFragment, GameFragment......).

Here are some steps:

```
F1 -> add fragment f1;
F1 -> add fragment f2;
F2 -> add fragment g1;
F2 -> add fragment g2;
F1 -> add fragment f3;
```

Now I want to use the transaction fragment on Container F2.
I mean:
I can add/remove a fragment on Container F2. But in android Fragment Manager will manager all Fragment f1..f3, g1..g2;
So I called popBackStack -> It's will remove fragment f3. (But I want to remove g2).

For any task like addFragment, remove, replace fragment I only want to do Fragment in Container F2. (F1 will be never changed).

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you adding the fragment, you can use `addToBackStack(String name)` and `disallowAddToBackStack()` to control the back stack of `FragmentManager`.

For your requirement, you should use the code like this to add f1, f2, and f3:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.F1, [your fragment instance])
    .disallowAddToBackStack()
    .commit();
```

And use the code like below to add g1 and g2:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.F2, [your fragment instance])
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Check the officail document of [`addToBackStack(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) and [`disallowAddToBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#disallowAddToBackStack()) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use child fragment when adding child to that fragment.

```
public void addFragB() {
        FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
        FragmentClassB fragB = new FragmentClassB();
        childFragTrans.add(R.id.fragA_LinearLayout, fragB);
        childFragTrans.addToBackStack("B");
        childFragTrans.commit();

    }
```

And when removing the fragment

```
    public void backPressed() {

        int childCount = parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (childCount == 0) {
            // it has no child Fragment                 
        } else {
            // get the child Fragment 
            FragmentManager childFragmentManager = parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager();                
            // removing the child Fragment from stack 
            childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();     
        }
    }
```

Comment: I not use Child Fragment :|,
In this case: I have 2 FrameLayout to container fragment. (Not fragment inside fragment) :|

Comment: He doesn't have nested fragments